# Magento 2 - How to check if custom route exists

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, routes

It's quite straight forward to check if a request url exists in a store scope via url_rewrites.

However, I'm wondering if there is a way to check if a custom route exists (as they don't have an entry in url_rewrites).

I.e. if I have

```
<?php

class \MyCompany\MyModule\Controller\Index\All extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
```

and declared my frontend route

```
<route id="mymodule" frontName="mymodule">
```

How to check if mymodule/index/all is a valid request_path (obviously we can try to request this path and will get a HTTP 200 response but I'm trying to avoid going down that path).

Comment: Just trying to save you some time. I went down this route(no pun intended) awhile ago and there isn't really any good way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate that.

Comment: Check out **matchAction** method in vendor **\Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base**.
That will return an actionInstance if it is found. For 200 status code, i think, you can try to call execute method from the instance and validate result (depends on response type).